# Copy data from a .vb file into a .txt

Tags: java

I have to generate is to add to the txt in each line for example 0001, in the next one 0002, etc. And if the code detect and error while im runnig the programa iit shows the message fo example the data doesnt have ")" ro something like that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        FileReader fr = null;
        FileWriter fw = null
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\etc");
            fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\etc\\example.txt");
            int c = fr.read();
            while(c!=-1) {
                fw.write(c);
                c = fr.read();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
        } finally {
            close(fr);
            close(fw);
        }
    }
    public static void close(Closeable stream) {
        try {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I need to generate numbers from 0001 and above in every line of the .txt file, if the code encounter and error during the .vb analysis it have to shown that error in the .txt with a message. For example Error 01 the code doesn't have ; in this line or something like that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to log errors (error message, line in your *.vb file which threw an exception) from your code into a *.txt file?

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag?

Comment: Please do not edit your post to a completely different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\etc\\example.vb");
            fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\etc\\example.txt");
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String line;
            int lineNumber = 1;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Check if the line contains an error
                if (line.contains(")")) {
                    bw.write("Error " + String.format("%02d", lineNumber) + ": The code doesn't have ';' in this line.\n");
                }
                // Append line number and write the line to the file
                bw.write(String.format("%04d", lineNumber++) + ": " + line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(br);
            close(fr);
            close(bw);
            close(fw);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Closeable stream) {
        try {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code reads each line from the input .vb file, checks if it contains a ) character, and if so, writes an error message to the output .txt file. It also adds line numbers in the format you specified (e.g., “0001:”, “0002:”, etc.) before each line in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

```
int lineNumber = 1;

try {
    fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\etc\\your_vb_file.vb");  // Specify the VB file path
    fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\etc\\example.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Check for errors in the VB code (you can add more checks as needed)
        if (!line.endsWith(";")) {
            fw.write(String.format("Error %04d - Missing semicolon at the end of line%n", lineNumber));
        }

        // Write the line number and line to the .txt file
        fw.write(String.format("%04d %s%n", lineNumber, line));
        lineNumber++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  // Print the error stack trace for debugging
    // You can also write the error message to the .txt file if needed
} finally {
    close(fr);
    close(fw);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue that had the person before the code? Actually, it's seems to be a code-only answer which is not really appreciated on SO